# Add a context menu item in windows explorer only for a specifc drive

Tags: .net, windows-shell

I would like to add a context menu item in windows explorer, a bit like notepadd++, winzip, winrar.

These are my requirements :

- The context menu item should be displayed on all files of a specific drive (for example : should be displayed on D: but not on C:)
- The context menu should just launch a .NET program with the selected file(s) as parameters
- Should work on XP, Vista, Windows 7 (32 and 64 bits)

After a bit of searching, it looks as though I could use the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell registry key and plug myself here but it looks as though it's all or nothing, no way to have my item just in the context menu for files in D: but not C:

The other solution would be to write a Shell Extension, but this is discouraged in .NET, and looks a bit overkill for the task at hand.

What is the simplest way to solve my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Writing a shell extension is at least a supported scenario as of .net 4.0.  However there may be better examples for unmanaged shell extensions and it may therefore actually be easier to write an unmanaged extension.

Comment: see this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648332/how-i-can-add-a-entry-to-shell-menu-only-on-drive-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The other solution would be to write a Shell Extension, but this is
>   discouraged in .NET, and looks a bit overkill for the task at hand.

where did you read it is discouraged? Dino Esposito has written a whole book on Shell Extensions done in C#, google for it :)

in a ShellExtension your code is executed and you have full control on what to display and when, it's not overkilling is what you need in this case.

The registry contains the ShellExtension registration (plus other things), so I believe you should go for coded shell extension approach not touching the registry manually because in this second case you have less control on what happens.

Comment: Thanks Davide, this is where I read it is discouraged : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx
It looks as though this is now supported in .NET 4.0, but can .NET 4.0 be considered mainstream now ?

Comment: My google skills are failing at finding the book you're talking about. Dino Esposito wrote a book about Windows Shell Programming in C++ right, but c# ? Do you have a link ? Nothing on Amazon either ...

Comment: Sorry I could have confused the book and it was in C++. check this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell1.aspx I do know I read articles on Shell Extensions in C#.

Comment: I finally went the .NET route ... For various reasons I couldn't go with C++. In some rare cases the extension won't load, but it's a price we can pay.