# How i can add a Entry to Shell Menu only on drive C:\?

Tags: windows, shell, registry

I need to add a Context Menu Item to Explorer Shell in Windows. This is easy doing by adding some Registgry Entry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Disk cleanup\command]
@="cleanmgr.exe"
```

but i like to add this entry only for drive C:\ or so. How i can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. (Works on Windows 7 here.)

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Disk cleanup\command]
@="cleanmgr.exe" 
"AppliesTo"="C:"
```

See [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more about the `AppliesTo` field.

I don't see the exact usage above listed for drives but it seems to work and mimics other listed usages.

Comment: Oh yeah! That works :) Thank you Etan you are the best :) (Yes the Usage is different :))